# Use tab bar button to reset view?

Tags: ios, ios8, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a tab controller which is displaying my home screen. In my home screen, there are optional filters for my collection view there. I would like the filters to be reset if the user taps on the same tab bar button. Currently, tapping on the tab bar button doesn't do anything if you are already in the same view of the tab bar button. How can I execute code if the tab bar button was tapped a second time?

Comment: I don't know any easy and elegant way to achieve what you want. Perhaps you could add an invisible button over the active tab? 

BTW you should try to formulate your question so that it expresses a clear question which can be given an answer. You shouldn't ask for opinions or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method in a UITabBarController subclass or put tabbar delegate in your controller.

```
    override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
        var isStatusbarWhite = false
       for xx in (tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem]){
        for var i:Int = 0 ; i < self.tabBar.items?.count ; ++i {
            let xx = tabBar.items![i] as! UITabBarItem
            if (xx == item){
               if tabBarController.selectedIndex == i {
//YOUR CODE HERE SAME TAB SELECTED
}
            }
        }

    }
```